# Does it hurt to go through time travel?

Tags: the-terminator-series, the-terminator

At the beginning of the movie, we see Kyle Reese come out of the time warp and apparently, he is in a bit of pain. Was he in pain from the fall or is the transportation portal actually painful to go through?

Bonus: Or was this foreshadowing that he was actually somewhat injured prior to escaping into the time warp, assuming in the future, the resistance was JUST ABLE to get him in before the Terminators had shown up?

Answer (score 7):

The film's [official novelisation](https://terminator.fandom.com/wiki/The_Terminator_(Frakes_novel)) and [original script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Terminator.html) indicate that the TDE (Time Displacement Equipment) is **massively painful** to use. Electrical shock, loud noise and swirling motion all combine to make it a very unpleasant ride indeed.

> When Kyle Reese came blasting through, he was high and off-center. His body stabilized in this temporal continuum a good two meters above the ground. He hung there for a microsecond; then gravity took over and slammed him into the alley floor with a loud, flat whack.
>
> He lay there, naked and trembling, eyes shut tight against the searing
> light, fists clenched against his chest, knees drawn up like an
> overgrown fetus. Spasms wracked every muscle in his body. After the
> explosion the wall of sound had ceased, leaving only the rustle of
> papers settling back to earth.
>
> The sickening odor of singed hair filled Reese’s nostrils, choking
> him. Pain was shooting through every fiber of his body. They didn’t
> tell him it was going to be like this, he thought. Maybe they didn’t
> know. But oh, fuck ...
>
> **it hurt.**
>
> He took it slow, marshaling his resources, sipping at the ozone-filled
> air until he could draw real breaths. The feeling of having his nuts
> kicked up into his chest cavity was abating. A little. He opened his
> eyes and saw ghosts; afterimages of sights that had yanked at his
> sanity like salt-water taffy.

and

> The rain washes a fine coating of white ash from his skin as
> electrical ARCS lace back and forth between the fire escapes behind
> him, HISSING and SPUTTERING.  The sound fades, then stops altogether,
> to be replaced by **a rising scream of animal agony**.
>
> Reese lurches to his feet and sprints across the alley.

For a hardened warrior like Reese, dropping a few feet to the floor was a mere annoyance by comparison.